# Overwriting bool property convention in fluent NHHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapper, convention

I am experimenting with the automap feature of Fluent Nhibernate..

I saw [an example](http://fnhsamples.codeplex.com/) which had a default string convention [as follows](http://fnhsamples.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/69709#443726):

```
namespace Vuscode.Framework.NHibernate.Conventions
{
    using FluentNHibernate.Conventions;
    using FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances;

    public class DefaultStringPropertyConvention : IPropertyConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Length(100);
            instance.Nullable();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, I see nothing that checks if the `instance` is of string type.. it just makes the length 100 and nullable.. How does Automapper knows to apply this convention only to strings?

Furthermore, I'd like to make all my bools non nullable and set a default value of 0.. so Following the above example, I'd have this:

```
namespace Vuscode.Framework.NHibernate.Conventions
{
    using FluentNHibernate.Conventions;
    using FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Instances;

    public class DefaultBoolPropertyConvention : IPropertyConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
        {
            instance.Not.Nullable();
            instance.Default("0");
        }
    }
}
```

But if I do that and have default string convention as well in my project.. then how does automapper know where which property types the convention is applied to?

I tried reading the [fluent wiki on conventions](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions) but did not find anything useful there..

Comment: Have not tested... ` if(instance.Type.GetUnderlyingSystemType() == typeof(bool))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the stringconvention is applied to all properties but since NHibernate ignores length for non string properties and nullable is the default it just has no effect. You have two options to filter non bool properties

```
public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
{
    if (instance.Type == typeof(bool))
    {
        instance.Not.Nullable();
        instance.Default("0");
    }
}

// or

public class DefaultBoolPropertyConvention : IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(i => i.Type == typeof(bool));
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Not.Nullable();
        instance.Default("0");

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I think the second one feels better.. Thanks so much!